# Word Interop Text replace in header adding extra spaces

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

Morning Everyone,

using interop.word to do a find/replace in the header.  It works but word, in it's great wisdom, adds spaces: 1 space to the beginning of each line after the first, 2-3 spaces at the end of each line.
So it looks like this but it should be completely left:

```
Sept 2, 2015
 first name   
 last name  
 address
```

I am looking at the text of the header after replacement using headerfooter.range.text and there are no extra spaces so it has to be an auto-formatting issue that word is obsessed with.

Thanks for any help!

---

What I have tried with no luck:

`paragraphformat.duplicate before and reset after
range.paragraphformat.spacebefore = 0
range.paragraphformat.spaceafter = 0`

```
Dim info As String = Now.ToLongDateString & vbCrLf & Trim(PersonInformation.FullName) & vbCrLf & Trim(PersonInformation.Address)
info &= vbCrLf & Trim(PersonInformation.City & ", " & PersonInformation.State & " " & PersonInformation.Zip)
hf.Range.Find.Execute(TagToReplace, , , , , , , , , info)
```

---

**UPDATED**

Found the answer.  It is how word/interop interprets vbcrlf when generating the doc.  Using just vbcr did the trick.  vblf also caused the inserted space.  Incidentally, vbNewLine also caused the extra space to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. It is how word/interop interprets vbcrlf when generating the doc. Using just vbcr did the trick. vblf also caused the inserted space. Incidentally, vbNewLine also caused the extra space to appear.